# How to make WordPress search find only products and also search custom attributes?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm looking for a way to hook onto he standard WordPress search so that it can search WooCommerce products' custom attributes. For example, if I have a custom attribute on a product called "Foo", how would I include that in the search results? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Look into this file from a woocommerce plugin to search for SKU:

https://github.com/wp-plugins/search-by-sku-for-woocommerce/blob/master/wc-searchbysku-widget-compat.php

1. User filter hook `posts_search`, you got the `where` part for the SQL search
2. Perform you custom search and collect the product ID's that will match
3. Extend the `where` part whith the collected product ID's and retrun it

To limit the search to products, you just have to add `post_type=product`:

`http://your-shop.com/?s=searchstring&post_type=product`

Comment: You saved me! I saw this but didn't think it would work with the standard WordPress search. It did!

Comment: Any idea how I might extend this to add a new attribute to search by? My PHP skills aren't that great.